# Pointer Arithmetic, Pass by Reference

Tags: c++

I got the following question from a past exam paper:

Consider the following source code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char dest[20];
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "demo" ) );
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "demo2" ) );
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "longer" ) );
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "even longer" ) );
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "and a really long string" ) );
}
```

Provide an implementation for the function called altcopy() which uses pointer arithmetic to copy alternate characters of a C-type string to the destination (i.e. the first, third, fifth etc character). Your answer must not use the [] operator to access an array index. The above code would then output the following:

```
dm
dm2
lne
ee ogr
adaral ogsrn
```

And I have attempted as follows:

```
using namespace std;

char* altcopy (char* dest, const char* str)
{
  char* p = dest;
  const char* q = str;

  for ( int n=0; n<=20; n++ )
  {
    *p = *q;
    p++;
    q++;
    q++;
  }
  return dest;
}

int main()
{
   char dest[20];
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "demo" ) );
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "demo2" ) );
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "longer" ) );
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "even longer" ) );
   printf( "%s\n", altcopy( dest, "and a really long string" ) );
}
```

And the results are:

```
dm
dm2lne
lne
ee ogradaral ogsrn
adaral ogsrn
```

I'm not sure why it happened to have duplicate of next statement result on certain output instead of performing as what the question asked for. Any help here?

Comment: What is the point of `using namespace std;` if there are no `#include`s?

Comment: Also this could be tagged C.

Comment: @MarcGlisse a bad habit is a bad habit.

Comment: What do you think happens for `n=18` while handling a short string like "demo"?

Comment: If this function is supposed to be like `strcpy`, you should probably always explicitly NUL-terminate the output.

Comment: Some useful answers, but also you don't need to make the local copies `p` and `q` since you're passing `dest` and `str` not by reference, but by value. `char*` can instead be a reference to a pointer like this: `char*&`, on a side note, your loop can be reduced to `*p++ = *q++; q++;`

Comment: The `q` copy of `src` isn't needed but a copy of `dest` is necessary so that the original can be returned to satisfy the given function contract.

Comment: @user3688544 See my answer. I showed the best solution.:) Your realization is totally wrong even with the help of other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is invalid at least because it uses magic number 20.
The function should be similar to standard function `strcpy` That is it has to copy the source string until the terminating zero will be encountered.

Here is a simple function realization

```
#include <iostream>

char * altcopy( char *dest, const char *str )
{
    char *p = dest;

    while ( *p++ = *str++ )
    {
        if ( *str ) ++str;
    }

    return dest;
}

int main()
{
    char dest[20];

    std::cout << altcopy( dest, "demo" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << altcopy( dest, "demo2" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << altcopy( dest, "longer" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << altcopy( dest, "even longer" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << altcopy( dest, "and a really long string" ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
dm
dm2
lne
ee ogr
adaral ogsrn
```

Enjoy!:)

Answer (score 0):

Since in your loop:

```
for ( int n=0; n<=20; n++ )
{
    *p = *q;
    p++;
    q++;
    q++;
}
```

you are just looping 20 times regardless of the string length you are reading random memory from past the end of the string. In most cases you probably read a 0 after the real characters and write that next which terminates the string as far as printf is concerned, but sometimes because the way the strings happen to be stored in memory you are getting some characters from the next string.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `q++` is being done twice, and it skips over the terminating null, and into the next string.
In fact it doesn't even check for the terminating null.

Comment: thank you so much for the feedback and it make sense that it could have skipped the null. is there a better way to loop so that it doesnt? i have tried while (*q) method but ended up no where.

Comment: @user3688544 The better loop is shown in my answer.

Comment: @Vlad: If the OP is clearly new to programming, I usually try to give just enough info so they can figure it out.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey It is a good idea. I usually write the whole solution because it is simpler for me to write a program than notes in English.:)

Comment: @Vlad: Your English is very good. I barely know the Cyrillic alphabet.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey The Cyrillic alphabet is more complicated than the Latin alphabet.:)